# Making a new floor pattern

Tags: color, images, image-editing

How do i change the pattern 1 tile (used in the first image, the inside of the castle) to look like the pattern 2 in the second image (the castle roof)

I just want to change the color of the pattern to be as close as the one on the roof (the white and light blue grey color) without too much degrading the drawn scuff marks and bricks.
I tried using Photoshop but i can never get the dark grey to go lighter without fading the black color of the drawn scuff marks and bricks.

i dont have the pattern from the roof, and just want to make it using the pattern i have, since its the same just darkened.

[image: how the pattern 1 looks in use]
[image: how the pattern 2 looks in use]
[image: how pattern 1 looks like a tile]

Comment: I'm not sure if this question can be answered without knowing how it was made.

Comment: What are you using to edit the image? Do you have access to the source file? What software was used to create it? Can you [edit] your question to add more details?

Answer (score 1):

An easy to understand method:

The unwanted pattern really seems to be generally darker, but there's also color hue differeces. I tried to adjust color balance and automatic color matching, but the result was not good. There's one example at the end of the answer. The colored areas must be fixed separately.

The brightest part is only darker. You must add contrast until the brightest area match. In Photoshop or other bitmap image editor you can adjust Curves:

[image]

In the left side there's a piece of the wanted version as a new layer for reference. Curves is temporarily applied only to the left half to make the effect visible in this answer.

Then you can select with the magic wand separately colored areas one by one. You must experiment a little with wand's selection tolerance. Alternatively you can select a color range. In Photoshop it's in the Select menu.  After selecting one color range pick the wanted color from the wanted version and paint manually with a BIG brush over the image. The result after replacing the colors:

[image]

It's not exact, but maybe acceptable.

Here's the best result that I got with color balance. It was applied after the brightness was fixed:

[image]

**Not asked:** You can make the textures exactly same by changing the roof, too.